# Cayley–Menger determinant.

Tags: matrices, determinant, simplex

Consider $n$-simplex. I read that  [Cayley–Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) is a squared-volume of simplex. But I don't know how to get it.

Actually after some attempts I get this : $\displaystyle V_s^2 = \frac 1 {(m!)^2}G(v_1\ldots v_n)$, where $G(v_1\dots v_n)$ is [Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix). But how can we transform Gramian to Cayley–Menger matrix? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you mentioned in your question are a bit inaccurate. Strictly speaking, suppose

- $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_m$ are $m+1$ points in $\mathbb R^n$, where $m\le n$;
- $X\in M_{n,m+1}(\mathbb R)$ is the augmented matrix $[x_0|x_1|\cdots|x_m]$;
- $Y\in M_{n,m}(\mathbb R)$ is the augmented matrix $[x_1-x_0|\cdots|x_m-x_0]$;
- $C\in M_{m+2}(\mathbb R)$ is the Cayley-Menger matrix $\pmatrix{0&e^T\\ e&B}$, where $B\in M_{m+1}(\mathbb R)$ is the squared distance matrix defined by $b_{ij}=\|x_i-x_j\|^2$ (in zero-based indexing) and $e\in\mathbb R^{m+1}$ is a vector of ones;
- $V$ is the volume of the $m$-simplex with vertices $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_m$ on the $m$-dimensional affine plane they lie on.

Then
$$
V^2 = \frac1{(m!)^2}\det(Y^TY) = \frac{-1}{(-2)^m (m!)^2} \det(C).\tag{1}
$$
In other words, the Cayley-Menger determinant is related to the Gram determinant as follows:
$$
\det(C) = -(-2)^m \det(Y^TY).\tag{2}
$$
Note that the Gramian here is **not** the Gramian of the data matrix $X$, but the Gramian of the reduced data matrix $Y$. Conceptually, if you want to calculate the volume by using Gramian, you should adopt a coordinate system in which a vertex of the simplex is located at the origin.

We may derive $(2)$ directly. Let $d=(\|x_0\|^2,\ldots,\|x_m\|^2)^T\in\mathbb R^{m+1}$ be the diagonal of $X^TX$. Since $b_{ij}=\|x_i\|^2-2\langle x_i,x_j\rangle+\|x_j\|^2$, we have
$$
C=\pmatrix{0&e^T\\ e&de^T+ed^T-2X^TX}.\tag{3}
$$
Subtract $d$ times the first row from other rows, and $d$ times the first column from other columns, we get
$$
\det(C)=\det\pmatrix{0&e^T\\ e&-2X^TX}.\tag{4}
$$
Now, if we subtract the second column from the third, the fourth up to the last column, and do the similar for the rows, we obtain
$$
\det(C)=\det\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&e_1^T\\ e_1&-2[x_0|Y]^T[x_0|Y]}}_{\widetilde{C}},\tag{5}
$$
where $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$. Since the last $m$ entries on the first row of $\widetilde{C}$ are zero, if $Y$ has linearly dependent columns, then the last $m$ columns of $\widetilde{C}$ are also linearly dependent and hence $(2)$ holds. If $Y$ has full column rank instead, then by multiplying $\widetilde{C}$ by
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&-(Y^TY)^{-1}Y^Tx_0&I_m}
$$
on the right, and also by $P^T$ on the left, we may obtain $(2)$:
$$
\det(C)=\det(\widetilde{C})=\det(P^T\widetilde{C}P)=\det\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 1&\ast&0\\ 0&0&-2Y^TY}=-(-2)^m\det(Y^TY).
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a result a bit more general.  Say we have points $P_1$, $\ldots$, $P_{n+1}$, and $Q_{1}$, $\ldots$, $Q_{n+1}$. Then the product of the oriented volume of the simplexes is a constant times the Cayley-Menger determinant of size $(n+2)\times (n+2)$, where the entries away from the first row and column are $d(P_i, Q_j)^2$.  There are two steps in the proof:

1. Come up with a bordered Gram determinant that is the product of the volumes. Here is the example for $n=2$.

\begin{eqnarray} \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & x_1 & y_1 & 0\\ 1& x_2 & y_2& 0 \\ 1& x_3 & y_3 & 0\end{matrix}\right )\cdot \left( 
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
0 & b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & x_1 a_1 + y_1 b_1  & x_1 a_2 + y_1 b_2 & x_1 a_3 + y_1 b_3\\
1 & x_2 a_1 + y_2 b_1  & x_2 a_2 + y_2 b_2 & x_2 a_3 + y_2 b_3\\
1 & x_3 a_1 + y_3 b_1  & x_3 a_2 + y_3 b_2 & x_3 a_3 + y_3 b_3\\
 \end{matrix} \right) \end{eqnarray}

2. The Cayley Menger determinant has off-border entries $\|P_i-Q_j\|^2 = -2 \langle P_i, Q_j\rangle + \|P_i\|^2 + \|Q_j\|^2$. Now check that for a bordered determinant of size $(n+2)$, changing the off-border entries like $f_{ij} \mapsto \alpha \cdot f_{ij} + \beta_i + \gamma_j$ changes the determinant  like $\Delta \mapsto \alpha^n \Delta$. This is seen by simple row and column operations.