# Volume of $n$-simplex in $\Bbb R^m$ without Cayley-Menger determinant

Tags: euclidean-geometry, simplex

The $n$-volume of an irregular $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m\gt n$ can be calculated by the [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) using squared edge lengths. Are there alternative approaches to calculate the $n$-volume if $m \gt n$ without using a Cayley-Menger determinant? Reshaped matrices (like [here](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath664/kmath664.htm)) that are in principal equal variants of the Cayley-Menger determinant  do not count.

Comment: I would do this as follows. Step1: calculate the $n$-volume of the parallelotope using [the Gram determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant). Step 2: divide by $n!$ to get the same for the simplex. Quite likely it amounts to the same. I had not heard of Cayley-Menger before. Using the parallelotope (kind of) assumes that the origin is at one of the vertices. If you are given the vertices of the simplex, simply parallel translate the whole think by subtracting one of the vectors from all the others.

Comment: Looks like [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2237799/11619) has the same description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one alternative method.

If $\ V_n\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\big)\ $ is the $n$-volume of the $n$-simplex $\ \mathcal{S}\ $with vertices $\ v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\ $, then
$$
V_n\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\big)=\frac{V_{n-1}\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\big)\big\|\big(I-P_{n-1}\big)\big(v_n-v_0\big)\big\|}{n}\ ,
$$
where $\ P_n\ $ is the perpendicular projection onto the $\ n-1$-dimensional space spanned by $\ v_{n-1}-v_0,$$v_{n-2}-v_0,$$\dots, v_1-v_0\ $.  The factor $\ \big\|\big(I-P_{n-1}\big)\big(v_n-v_0\big)\big\|\ $ in this product is just the height of the vertex $\ v_n\ $ above the $n-1$-simplex with vertices $\ v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\ $, taken as a base of $\ \mathcal{S}\ $. By induction, therefore,
$$
V_n\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\big)=\frac{1}{n!}\|v_1-v_0\|\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\big\|\big(I-P_j\big)\big(v_{j+1}-v_0\big)\big\|\ .
$$

#### Derivation of the formula

If $\ h_n=\big\|\big(I-P_{n-1}\big)\big(v_n-v_0\big)\big\|\ $ is the height of the vertex $\ v_n\ $ of the simplex $\ \mathcal{S}\ $ above its base, $\ \text{Conv}\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\big)\ $, and $\ A_{n-1}(x)\ $ is the $\ n-1$-volume of the cross-section of  $\ \mathcal{S}\ $ at height $\ x\ $ above that base, then the volume of $\ \mathcal{S}\ $ is
$$
\int_0^{h_n}A_{n-1}(x)dx\ .
$$
But the cross-section of $\ S\ $ at height $\ x\ $ above the base is the $\ n-1$-simplex with vertices $\ v_0(x),v_1(x), \dots, v_{n-1}(x)\ $, where
$
v_i(x)=\left(1-\frac{x}{h_n}\right)v_i+\left(\frac{x}{h_n}\right)v_n
$. This simplex is similar to the base $\ \text{Conv}\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\big)\ $, scaled down by a linear factor $\ \frac{x}{h_n}\ $ $\big($since $\ v_i(x)-v_j(x)=\left(\frac{x}{h_n}\right)\big(v_i-v_j\big)\ $$\big)$. Its $n-1$-volume $\ A_{n-1}(x)\ $is therefore $\ \left(\frac{x}{h_n}\right)^{n-1}V_{n-1}\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\big)\ $. The volume of $\ \mathcal{S}\ $ is therefore
\begin{align}
\int_0^{h_n}A_{n-1}(x)dx&=\int_0^{h_n}\left(\frac{x}{h_n}\right)^{n-1}V_{n-1}\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\big)dx\\
&=\frac{h_n\,V_{n-1}\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\big)}{n}\ ,
\end{align}
as stated above.  The formula is a generalisation of the instances that the area of a triangle is half the length of its base multiplied by its height, and the volume of a tetrahedron is one third of the area of its base multiplied by its height.

#### Simplification

The above formula can be written more simply if the Gram-Schmidt procedure is used to orthonormalise the vectors $\ v_1-v_0,v_2-v_0,\dots, v_n-v_0\ $:
\begin{align}
u_1&=\frac{v_1-v_0}{\big\|v_1-v_0\big\|}\ ,\\
u_j&=\frac{v_j-v_0 -\sum_\limits{i=1}^{j-1}\left\langle v_j-v_0,u_i\right\rangle}{\big\|v_j-v_0 -\sum_\limits{i=1}^{j-1}\left\langle v_j-v_0,u_i\right\rangle\big\|}
\end{align}
for $\ j=2,3,\dots,n\ $. Then $\ \big(I-P_j\big)\big(v_{j+1}-v_0\big)=$$\left\langle\big(v_{j+1}-v_0\big),u_{j+1}\right\rangle u_{j+1}\ $, and $\ \big\|\big(I-P_j\big)\big(v_{j+1}-v_0\big)\big\|=$$\left\langle\big(v_{j+1}-v_0\big),u_{j+1}\right\rangle\ $. Therefore
$$
V_n\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\big)=\frac{\prod_\limits{j=0}^{n-1}\left\langle\big(v_{j+1}-v_0\big),u_{j+1}\right\rangle}{n!}\ .
$$

#### Postscript

It's occurred to me that the orthonormalisation, $\ u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n\ $, of $\ v_1-v_0,v_2-v_0,\dots, v_n-v_0\ $ allows one to define an isometry $\ v_0+\sum_\limits{i=1}^nx_iu_i\mapsto\big(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\big)\ $ from the affine hull of $\ \mathcal{S}\ $ onto $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $.  The image of $\ \mathcal{S}\ $ under this isometry will be an $n$-simplex in $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $  congruent to $\ \mathcal{S}\ $, and therefore having the same volume.  Therefore any of the [well-known formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume) for the volume of an $n$-simplex in $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $ will give another method for calculating the volume of $\ \mathcal{S}\ $.

Comment: Interesting. Could you recommend a source where this is described in more detail?

Comment: I'm not aware of any source where this method of calculating the volume of a simplex is treated. However, the idea behind it (of which I've now added a few more details) is fairly simple, and I'm virtually certain that it  can't be original.