# Name for the formula for $n$-simplex volume?

Tags: geometry, simplex

> What is the name for the general relation of the volume of an $n$-simplex shown in $(\star\star)$ below? In which specific books I can find the formula?

Some words about the meaning of equation $(\star\star)$

The general relation $(\star\star)$ is derived from $(\star)$. Special cases of $(\star)$ are equations (1-3), i.e. the length of a line segment $(n=1)$ from its base point, the area of a triangle $(n=2)$ from its base length, and the volume of a tetrahedron $(n=3)$ from its base area:

$$\begin{align}
\text{line length}\;&=\;\frac{\text{1 [Point]} \times \text{height}}{1!} \tag{1}\\[6pt]
\text{triangle area}\;&=\;\frac{\text{base length} \times \text{height}}{2!} \tag{2}\\[6pt]
\text{tetrahedron volume}\;&=\;\frac{\text{base area} \times \text{height}}{3!} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

The formula $(\star)$ below gives the $n$-volumes for any $n$ using its $(n-1)$-volume and the height. The formula $(\star\star)$ gives the $n$-volume without knowing the $(n-1)$-volume. The proof can be found in this [Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3999102/737314). What is the name of the relation $(\star\star)$ and in which book it is derived?

---

---

---

If $\ V_n\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\big)\ $ is the $n$-volume of the $n$-simplex $\ \mathcal{S}\ $with vertices $\ v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\ $, then
$$
V_n\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\big)=\frac{V_{n-1}\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\big)\big\|\big(I-P_{n-1}\big)\big(v_n-v_0\big)\big\|}{n}\ ,
\tag{$\star$}$$
where $\ P_n\ $ is the perpendicular projection onto the $\ n-1$-dimensional space spanned by $\ v_{n-1}-v_0,$$v_{n-1}-v_0,$$\dots, v_1-v_0\ $.  The factor $\ \big\|\big(I-P_{n-1}\big)\big(v_n-v_0\big)\big\|\ $ in this product is just the height of the vertex $\ v_n\ $ above the $n-1$-simplex with vertices $\ v_0,v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}\ $, taken as a base of $\ \mathcal{S}\ $. By induction, therefore,
$$
V_n\big(v_0,v_1,\dots,v_n\big)=\frac{1}{n!}\|v_1-v_0\|\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\big\|\big(I-P_j\big)\big(v_{j+1}-v_0\big)\big\|\ \tag{$\star\star$}$$

Comment: About hyper-simplices, an interesting [PhD thesis](http://web.mit.edu/~dorian/Public/thesis.pdf).

Comment: (Using tag numbers I added) Your equations $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ are special cases of $(\star)$, not $(\star\star)$, so they should have denominators $1$, $2$, $3$, not $1!$, $2!$, $3!$. (Of course, as a matter of calculation, only the last of these is actually in error. :)

Comment: I don't think "a hypercuboid's volume is the product of the lengths of edges at a vertex" has a name either.